# Put a button in front of all rows in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables. It is being populated with JSON data from a database. I can't figure out how to display a button or link in front of each record. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on that button then that particular record gets added in the database, so the button or link should contain an ID. Please help sort out my problem.
Below is the code I'm using:

```js
var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable();

$.ajax({
  url: 'process.php?method=fetchdata',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(s) {
    console.log(s);
    oTable.fnClearTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      oTable.fnAddData([
        s[i][3],
        s[i][4],
        s[i][0], // this contains id
      ]);
    }
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e.responseText);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="jsontable" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Class Number</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>ADD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is help

```js
oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex) {
     //nRow  Row Object
     //aaData Param
     //iDisplayIndex Row Index
     $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html("<input type='button'>Button</input>");
                    return nRow;
                }
        });
```

Comment: That doesn't pull any row from the JSON. OP needs some way to know the ID associated with each row when the button is clicked.

Comment: @redbmk isn't that what the `iDisplayIndex` var is for?

Comment: @S.Buda Well, the ID is coming from the database, in `s[i][0]`. DataTables allows you to sort the dataset, so I'd imagine `iDisplayIndex` just tells you the index of the row in the sorted dataset.

Comment: @redbmk Ah yes, of course, sort of skimmed the question/answer. However, I think Silence Peace has it close, if he just uses the id field from aaData and put that into his `input` it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to do something like this? (Also, this may be for an older version of datatables, now that I think about it. This is syntax for version 1.9, and I would guess you're using a more recent version (1.10+) The syntax may be a little different, but it should be documented in [the api docs.](https://datatables.net/api)

```
    $('#jsontable').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource" : "process.php?method=fetchdata",
        "aoColumns" : [
            { "mData": function(source) {
                    return '<input type="button" value=' + source[0] + '/>';
            }},
            { "mData": function(source) {
                    return source[1];
            }},
            { "mData": function(source) {
                    return source[2];
            }}
        }
    });
```

Obviously, your button can look however you want, you probably don't want the id stored on the value. You can do what you need with it.